# Circle objects register a collision, but they are not touching

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

I just checked [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions) to make sure this question was allowed, and it seems that it is so here I go:

I am currently making a 2D physics engine as a small project. I have a class called `circle` which has properties such as radius, rotation, position, and velocity:

```
class circle():
    def __init__(self, radius = 10, r = 0.0, x = 0, y = 0, Vr = 0, Vx = 0, Vy = 0):

        self.radius = radius

        self.r = r
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.Vr = Vr
        self.Vx = Vx
        self.Vy = Vy
```

The class has a method called `CheckCollisions()`, which checks if the distance between its centre and another circle's centre is less than the sum of their radii:

```
def CheckCollisions(self):
    for c in circles:
        distance = math.sqrt((c.x - self.x)*(c.x - self.x) + (c.y - self.y)*(c.y - self.y))
        if distance < self.radius + c.radius:
            print('!')
        else:
            print('')
```

The idea is that on detecting the collision, forces can be applied as vectors to each object as a response to the impact.

When my code runs, I see constant exclamation marks appearing in the shell, despite the circles not colliding. What is causing this? Perhaps something in my calculation of distance is incorrect?

---

Full code:

```
import pygame, random, math
from pygame.locals import*

# set up pygame window
(width, height) = (1000, 800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Impulse Physics v0.1 BETA')

pen = pygame.image.load('Pen.png').convert()
background = (0, 0, 0)

class circle():
    def __init__(self, radius = 10, r = 0.0, x = 0, y = 0, Vr = 0, Vx = 0, Vy = 0):

        self.radius = radius

        # position and rotation
        self.r = r
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        # velocity
        self.Vr = Vr
        self.Vx = Vx
        self.Vy = Vy

    def CheckCollisions(self):
        for c in circles:
            # use pythagoras to find direct distance between centres
            distance = math.sqrt((c.x - self.x)*(c.x - self.x) + (c.y - self.y)*(c.y - self.y))
            if distance < self.radius + c.radius:
                print('!')
            else:
                print('')

    def Move(self):
        # apply slight "air resistance"
        self.Vx = self.Vx * 0.9999
        # gravity. REMEMBER y axis is inverted in pygame!
        self.Vy = self.Vy + 0.15

        # move object
        self.x = self.x + self.Vx
        self.y = self.y + self.Vy
        self.r = self.r + self.Vr

        self.CheckCollisions()

        # check if colliding with the sides of the window
        if self.y + self.radius > height:
            self.Vy = self.Vy * -0.98
            self.y = self.y + self.Vy

        if (self.x + self.radius > width) or (self.x - self.radius < 0):
            self.Vx = self.Vx * -0.98
            self.x = self.x + self.Vx

    def Render(self):
        penX = self.x
        penY = self.y
        penR = self.r
        screen.blit(pen, (penX, penY))

        # draw the radius of the circle
        for counter in range(self.radius):
            penX = self.x + (math.sin(penR) * counter)
            penY = self.y - (math.cos(penR) * counter)
            screen.blit(pen, (penX, penY))

        # draw the circumference of the circle
        for counter in range(self.radius * 20):
            penR = counter * (360 / self.radius * 20)
            penX = self.x + (math.sin(penR) * self.radius)
            penY = self.y + (math.cos(penR) * self.radius)
            screen.blit(pen, (penX, penY))

circles = []

#create objects here

c1 = circle(100, 0, 400, 400, 0.1, 4)
circles.append(c1)

c2 = circle(50, 0, 50, 50, 0.08, 10)
circles.append(c2)

c3 = circle(10, 0, 300, 200, 0.02, -3)
circles.append(c3)

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(background)
    for obj in circles:
        obj.Move()
        obj.Render()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It always collides with itself.

Comment: `sqrt` is expensive. Compare `distance_squared` with `self.radius**2 + c.radius**2`

Comment: @PeterWood so, remove the sqrt function and used the squared values?

Comment: @AricFowler what do you think?

Comment: `self.radius**2 + c.radius**2` is wrong. Use `(self.radius + c.radius) ** 2`.

Comment: @BlakeO'Hare a^2 + b^2 is not equal to (a + b)^2. In pythagoras, you square both values and add the results together

Comment: @AricFowler yes, `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`. The sum of the radii is `c` so you must add them together first before squaring. `a` and `b` are the x and y components.

Comment: @BlakeO'Hare I understand, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: **a circle collides with itself**. The reason is simply that the `circles` list contains `[c1,c2,c3]` and thus checks are done against the circles themselves.

Now for `c1` you check whether there is a collision so it iterates over the `circles` and the first thing it checks is **whether it collides with itself** (since `c1` is the first element in the list). And obviously it does (your test looks if the distance is less than the sum of the circles radiuses, but the distance is zero). If none of the circles collide, there will thus be three exclamation marks (one for each circle).

You can resolve this error by performing a reference equality check first:

```
def CheckCollisions(self):
    for c in circles:
        if c is not self:
            distance = math.sqrt((c.x - self.x)*(c.x - self.x) + (c.y - self.y)*(c.y - self.y))
            #...
```

Comment: thank you! Self-collision will be useful to remember in the future, i think.